# How to write unittests for events in a database or something hard to test for?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a process where I'm querying a database in chunks of 100000, and I want to retry up to 5 times if it is a timeout error, otherwise send out an alert.  How could I write a `unittest` for this?  I'm not exactly sure how to simulate the environment so I can double check the logic.  It's also difficult to test the alert (it's an email), other than just sending it and seeing if it arrives.  How would you write a test for this?  Here is my code:

```
def _query_data(self, sql_query: str, retries: int = 5):
        cursor = self._return_cursor(self.canvas_conn)
        for attempt in range(retries):
            try:
                cursor.execute(sql_query)
            except (ppg2.ProgrammingError, ppg2.OperationalError) as e:
                if 'Operation timed out' in str(e):
                    print('Retrying, attempt {}'.format(attempt))
                    sleep(3)
                    continue
                elif self.historical_connect:
                    msg = 'Connected on last run, no longer available.'
                    self.set_for_alert(msg)
                    self.historical_connect = False
                raise ppg2.Error from e
            else:
                return self._iterate_results(cursor)
```

The error gets caught in the process that calls it.

Comment: Mock out the database?

Comment: How would I force it to timeout?

Comment: ...you don't. *The actual database isn't involved*. You just create a mock that simulates the behaviour you want.

Comment: Adding on to previous comments, a unit test should never touch a database, otherwise your test is dependent on that database working, being in a good state, etc.  Which is outside the scope of a unit test.  You mock out the database and you can simulate anything you need (including timeouts) http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/testing-for-failures-with-python/240169387